# Files using control codes instead of numbers

Tags: python, unicode

```py
level = 6

try:
    with open('highscore.txt', 'r+') as frplus:
        highscore = int(frplus.read())
        if level > highscore:
            frplus.truncate(0)
            frplus.write(str(level))
except FileNotFoundError:
    with open('highscore.txt', 'w') as fw:
        fw.write(str(0))
```

I'm testing a high score recording system for a game I'm making.

When I run this I get the error code:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x005'

I did some research and I think for some reason the file is printing the Unicode control codes to read the file instead of the numerical codes.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is actually that you are truncating the file but not writing at the start of the file. This means the first byte of the file is `0x00`, the null byte. Just add `frplus.seek(0)` after `frplus.truncate(0)` and it should work. You may need to delete the existing file before it works.